# Globally accessible filter for angular app

Tags: angularjs, filter

In an AngularJS app, I have a view with a list of tasks and a sidebar with a list of filtering options to filter those tasks. Both are in separate controllers.

**Sidebar**

```
<div ng-controller="SidebarController">
    <a href="" ng-click="showOnlyCompleted()">Completed</a>
</div>
```

**Tasks**

```
<div ng-controller="TaskController">
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: search">
        <td>task.title</td>
        <td>task.status</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

**SidebarController**

```
$scope.search = [];

$scope.showOnlyCompleted = function()
{
    // set search filter
    $scope.search.status = 'completed'; 
};
```

**TaskContoller**

```
$scope.tasks = [
    {   title: 'do something', status:'todo' },
    {   title: 'do something else', status:'completed' }
];
```

The question is, how can I make it such that the filter, `search`, can be manipulated through SidebarController, but can still be used to filter the tasks coming from TaskController? It's a scoping problem, because both controllers need to be able to have access to it?

I am thinking the solution might be something injectable, like a service, but I don't really know how to make that work for this case with data-binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw one nice solution for this [here](https://github.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-book/tree/master/chapter8/teams-list). Basically just create a filterService with some state, inject that to your controllers and bind to that directly in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the link, helped me to get this to work :) But I was wondering if there is a different way, e.g. by defining the filter using `myApp.filter` and then injecting that filter into the controller?

Comment: Filters defined as module level like `myApp.filter` are available at global level, and can be directly used in HTML where filter are required